# How do I scrape reviews on the web?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping

I want to scrape reviews about various products and things in the web, how can I do that. There is a company called searchreviews.com, they do it, I want to know how they do it.

Comment: Be aware that the TOS of a site might prevent your scraping and could result in being banned. Be a good citizen and don't beat up their servers, because it's their bandwidth you are consuming. Observe the "robots" rules for their site, and cache, cache, cache everything you can so you don't make redundant/recursive searches that waste your and their CPU time. And learn what a HEAD request is and USE it. Better yet, don't reinvent the wheel and use one of the existing spider apps like [anemone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: An explanation of downvotes may be helpful.

Comment: Scraping is difficult to maintain, find out if they have an API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They get a page's HTML then parse it, targeting whatever information they need.

It's really awful, because it depends on the DOM of the site you're scraping, which can change at any time, in both trivial and complex ways. I've worked with companies that have scraped (legitimately) various types of sites, and it's horrible.

Comment: Yep. Companies like these probably run a small army of codemonkeys to keep patching their scraping engines and algos. It's not impossible to do, but it's by no means a code-once-and-cash-in system. You will just need a strategy to keep maintaining the scraping code.

Comment: @Casper The best part is that one of them was a bank/financial account aggregator, so we'd regularly see requests with deposits of (a chunk of HTML) instead of numbers--they did a poor job of vetting *anything* instead relying on getting reports back from their downstream vendors and/or suppliers :(

Answer (score 1):

mechanize or watir or rautomation are related gems that might help you here.

Comment: yea they will help with the process but isn't there privacy on these sites that wont allow this to be done?

Comment: @user1452023 Depends entirely on the site. Browser signatures can be spoofed, timing can be randomized/humanized, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this very often for various clients, and most of the time a site that gathers reviews is pretty well structured, so scraping isn't too hard. Look at Yelp.com for example. I built a routine in screen-scraper that searched zip codes in the client's area, used the filters to hone in on the desired business types, and makes a list of unique results (since the zip code searches could render duplicate results). From there I hie each unique URL. The reviews are pretty easy to parse with just RegEx, and some page iteration.